# Monodevelop object permission default to private

Tags: monodevelop, access-modifiers

Running MonoDevelop 7.8.2. The designer creates code (in the gtk-gui/file.cs) that declares all objects as private. Is there a way to change the default so the objects are public?

I have looked for settings or preferences in MonoDevelop and don't see any setting for this. I don't know if there is a setting in the stetic xml file that can be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no setting to change the scope of these member variables that I'm aware of. You could experiment and change the generated code manually but be aware that its unlikely intended that you do this so, even if it works, it may not do in a future release of MonoDevelop.

You could contribute to the MonoDevelop project perhaps to implement this functionality...?